# Borders around AI images in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I made a booklet in InDesign with a couple of illustrator images. When I do Print Booklet and use Press Quality I get odd borders around the images:
[image]

I think it has to do with transparency flattening but how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

This happens a lot when transparency effects like drop shadows and opacity levels are used with spot color swatches. If you have any spot swatches, try setting them to output as process in the Ink Manager. It can also help to export using the PDF/X-1a:2001 Standard.